# How to get height & width of a img tag residing in a hidden container

Tags: jquery, html

I have a img tag in a div which is hidden, but when I try to get height and width of that img tag, It gives 0 - 0.

Here is my html

```
<div style="display:none">
  <img id="image" src="https://igcdn-photos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t51.2885-15/11357782_1454910574825551_630646141_n.jpg">
</div>
```

jQuery for getting height and width

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  height = $('#image').height();
  width = $('#image').width();
  alert('Height: '+height+' Width: '+width);
});
```

CSS

```
#image {height:200px; width:300px;}
```

I want to get 200 as height and 300 as width, I can do it with getting css of the element, but the height and width for #image would not be static, It would be in percentage and for that i need to get height and width on runtime without showing the image tag container.

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to FOUC a few seconds with the **jQuery** way! If it is okay for you, you can use this:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#get-image-size").show();
  a = {
    height: $("#get-image-size img").height(),
    width: $("#get-image-size img").width()
  };
  $("#get-image-size").hide();
  $("body").append(JSON.stringify(a));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="get-image-size" style="display: none;">
  <img id="image" src="https://igcdn-photos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t51.2885-15/11357782_1454910574825551_630646141_n.jpg" />
</div>
```

Or you may use the `new Image()` way in **pure JavaScript**:

```html
<div id="img"></div>
<script>
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "https://igcdn-photos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t51.2885-15/11357782_1454910574825551_630646141_n.jpg";
  img.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("img").innerHTML = '{"height": ' + this.height + ',"width": ' + this.width + '}';
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround, using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    var $target = $('#image');
    $target.parent().show();
    $target.hide().on('load', function(){
        alert( $(this).width() + ', ' + $(this).height() );
        $(this).parent().hide();
        $(this).show();
    });
});
```

[Check jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/uzrzhzw2/)

Comment: Try it with this html 

<div style="display: none;">
    <img id="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
</div>

It won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It worked too but this is the same answer as given by @Praveen

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, well, I tried to make a short piece of code, but your requirement made it to become in (almost) the same answer. There aren't lots of ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can load your img src in [`Image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) object

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = $('#image').prop('src');
    img.onload = function () {
        alert("height: " + this.height + " width:" + this.width);
    };
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j0728sos/)

Comment: I am not looking for actual height & width, I'm looking for image tag height & width.

Comment: @RohitKhatri, Then go ahead with praveen answer